# SetWindowsHookEx freeze my keyboard and mouse, and other strange things happends

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm writing joke program (makes strange sounds, where user use mouse or keyboard) in Delphi, which uses global hooks to capture mouse and keyboard events.
 
This is function responsible for handle this hook:

```
procedure MKHOOK(code: Integer;wp: wParam;lp: lParam); stdcall;
var
hh: HHOOK;
begin
  PlaySound('fart.wav');
  CallNextHookEx(hh,code,wp,lp);
end;
```

Hook starts, when Form is creating:

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MH := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,@MKHOOK,hInstance,0);
   KH := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,@MKHOOK,hInstance,0);
end;
```

Where MH and KH are type of HHOOK
Hook is deleted, when program ends:

```
procedure TForm6.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   UnhookWindowsHookEx(MH);
   UnhookWindowsHookEx(KH);
end;
```

Problems starts, when I try to run it there are strange things happends like:

- Mouse and keyboard stopped working, I must use ctrl + alt + del to recover it
- Some keys didn't working after program execution, when I stoped it (ctrl, alt, tab)
- Some keys change their behavior for example, when I used arrows keys, they turn my screen view.

What is wrong with this code? Why it not works?  Sorry for my English ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. The most obvious:

- The call to `PlaySound` is too expensive to make in a hook. It's liable to bring the system to its knees if you call `PlaySound` every time your hook executes.
- Your hook signatures are wrong. They need to be functions that return `LRESULT`. The required return value is described in the documentation in both cases as follows: *if nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.*
- You don't do any error checking. Always check API calls for errors. Error handling is discussed in the documentation for each API call.

The first parameter of `CallNextHookEx` is ignored so you may as well pass `0`. And it is cleaner to use separate hook procedures in my view.

The hook functions have to look like this:

```
function MouseHook(code: Integer; wp: wParam; lp: lParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, wp, lp);
end;

function KeyboardHook(code: Integer; wp: wParam; lp: lParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, wp, lp);
end;
```

Obviously these hooks don't do anything yet, but let's walk before we try to run.

Install the hooks like this:

```
MH := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @MouseHook, hInstance, 0);
if MH = 0 then
  // handle error
KH := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @KeyboardHook, hInstance, 0);
if KH = 0 then
  // handle error
```

I think it's clear that you have not read the documentation in sufficient detail. These APIs are tricky to use. You need precision in your coding. I recommend that you read the documentation again more closely.

Comment: "you pass an uninitialized variable as the hook parameter" - technically, `CallNextHookEx()` ignores the first parameter, so it doesn't matter what you pass to it.  You can pass 0 instead, in which case *could* use a single hook procedure for both hooks, but I would not recommend it. Two dedicated procedures is easier to manage.

Comment: @Remy Looks like I'm guilty of not reading the docs closely enough too!